# Android 9 (Pie) Only: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() - Works fine on Oreo

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

We adjusted our ongoing notification for Oreo and it worked great.  Now, on Pie only (not happening on Oreo devices), we're getting the titled error.  Has something changed in foreground services in Pie that I'm missing?

Here's the onCreate code for the foreground service ->

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, packageName)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.ongoing_notify_temp_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.ongoing_notify_temp_message))
            .setGroup(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ONGOING)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.custom_blue))
            .build()

    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFY_ID, notification)

    appSettings = AppSettings(this)

    weatherLookUpHelper = WeatherLookUpHelper()
    MyRoomDatabase.getInstance().invalidationTracker.addObserver(onChange)

    retrieveCurrentLocation()
    createAlarmManager()
}
```

as you can see, we're just creating the notification and then calling startForeground.  Any ideas on why this code would generate the titled error?

Side Note: Fabric Crashlytics shows this crash only happening on Pixel devices (pixel, pixel xl, pixel 2, pixel 2 xl) running Pie

**EDIT:** We do have the foreground permission in our manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Do you have this permission in your manifest `Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE`

Comment: @MayRestinPeace yes we do

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @knowledgeDrilling unfortunately not.  I've moved jobs since then and the project I'm on now doesn't have this issue so I doubt I'll be following up on this.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned here [Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), the app/service has five seconds to call `startForeground()`, If the app does not call startForeground() within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be ANR.

There are some possibilities:

1. Either your foreground service gets destroyed/finished before calling the  `startForeground()` method.
2. Or if  the foreground service is already instantiated and its getting called again, then the `onCreate` method will not be called, instead `onStartCommand` will be called. Then move your logic to `onStartCommand` to call `startForeground()` method.
3. Your notification id in `startForeground` [must not be 0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), otherwise it will also cause the crash.

Comment: would putting startForeground in onStartCommand risk anything with duplicate calls?

Comment: No, `onStartCommand` would get called after `onCreate` only once when you start the service. But, if you start the service multiple times, then of course `onStartCommand` would be called multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

> Has something changed in foreground services in Pie that I'm missing?

**YES**
Have a look here  [migration notes of Android 9 / Pie](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration#tya)

**Change**

Foreground service permission

**Summary**

Apps wanting to use foreground services must now request the [FOREGROUND_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#FOREGROUND_SERVICE) permission first. This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app. Starting a foreground service without the permission throws a SecurityException.

**UPDATE**

related  issue in Google Issue Tracker  [Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072)

Comment: @Psest328 can u share your log with question

Comment: @Psest328 there is  issue check here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072

Comment: @Psest328 can u share the value of your `ONGOING_NOTIFY_ID`

Answer (score 1):

1. I revert back to startService() instead of using startForeground() solved my issue.

Comment: Same issue here...after adding the API > Oreo check and using ```startForegroundService(intent)``` this is causing the crash even though I use ```startForeground(0, builder.build());``` in the service at ```onStartCommand```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped to get the error after implementing below code in `ONCREATE`

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
          try {
                startService(intent1);
            }catch ( Exception e1){
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    this.startForegroundService(intent1);
                }else {
                    Crashlytics.log("crash for first time, trying another.");
                    this.startService(intent1);
                }
            }
```

For me sounds strange but is working fine without crash.

Comment: It will not crash, but just service (not foreground) will not work, when application is closed from API > Android oreo